# The most basic Gmail app for Android

Tags: android, email-client, gmail

I just wondered if anyone had a suggestion for the most basic email app for Android.

The only features I want:

- write and send email to contacts
- read email in HTML and/or text
- forward/reply/reply-all
- report spam/phishing

Features I don't want:

- everything else

Willing to pay up to £5 for it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Tom! Maybe you could [edit] your post and add your price limit then? Also, while waiting for you to "come over", I've done a little editing to my listing of [Email Apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_emailapps). You might wish to check that while waiting for recommendations. Good luck!

Comment: Any special Gmail features required? From the features mentioned in your question, it doesn’t seem to be relevant that your provider is Gmail. Or does Gmail offer a phishing report function and the email client should be able to offer an interface for it?

Comment: @unor - yes these are all features of Gmail. I am not sure about other providers because I don't have any.